# How do I recursively reverse a list in python without an aux fnc

Tags: python, list, recursion

Write a function that reverses a string. The input string is given as an array of characters char[].

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

You may assume all the characters consist of printable ascii characters.

Example:

```
Input: ["h","e","l","l","o"]
Output: ["o","l","l","e","h"]
```

I'm fairly new to recursion so I looked up some possible solutions but I'm not sure why this one isn't outputting the desired result as it looks like it runs.

```
class Solution(object):

    def reverseString(self, s):
        """
        :type s: List[str]
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """
        if not s:
            return []
        else: 
            return [s[-1]] + self.reverseString(s[:-1])
```

Comment: Is there something in the problem statement which requires you to use recursion?

Comment: ^ yeah??? Why use recursion??

Comment: Your problem refers to "an array of characters, `char[]`". That's a description for a C or C++ problem (maybe Java or a few other languages too); there is no such thing as a `char[]` in Python. And as the other commenters have noted, it says nothing about recursion. It seems like you're solving a problem unrelated to the assignment.

Comment: I'll also note, your own docstring says ":rtype: None Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.", which is the opposite of what you're doing (you're returning a brand new `list`, leaving `s` unmodified).

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite as elegant of a solution, but it works.

```
def rev(arr, i=0):
    if i >= len(arr) // 2:
        return
    arr[i], arr[-(i + 1)] = arr[-(i + 1)], arr[i]
    rev(arr, i + 1)

test = ["t", "e", "s", "t"]


>>> test
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
>>> rev(test)
['t', 's', 'e', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive implementation :

```
    >>> L = ["h","e","l","l","o"]
    >>> L
    ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

    reverse = lambda L: (reverse (L[1:]) + L[:1] if L else [])

    >>> print(reverse(L))
    ['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
```

Comment: This is not O(1) because the elements of the array slices are copied, so it has to allocate new arrays at each level.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but assigning lambda functions to a name is against PEP8 style guidelines